# Can I replace just one string despite the existence of other strings with similar values in R

Tags: r, string, replace, na, grepl

I’m learning R. I want to replace a “0” string in a column of a data frame to NA value. This column  has other strings with “0” values include in them.

I’ve used:

```
For(n in 1:nrow(d2)) {
  If(grepl(“0”, d2[n,10]) == TRUE)
  d2[n,10] <- NA
```

And it work but it replace every strings that has a “0” (that column was a large answer question) many other strings had “0” in them with other information, but I don’t want to replace them, just the ones that have exclusively “0” in the cell.

If anyone knows how to exclusively replace the cells with “0” values, please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grep/grepl` is vectorized.  So, we can create a logical vector directly on the column and change it to `NA`

```
d2[,10][grepl("^0$", d2[,10])] <- NA
```

---

Or do a fixed match

```
d2[,10][d2[,10] == '0'] <- NA
```

Comment: Akrum THANKS A LOT YOU SAVE MEEEEE